# jquery social sharing widget cant set default 0 to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-likes

Ive spent the majority of my trying to troubleshoot this script to do what you would generally consider to be something super easy to do.

My Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pistachio_labs/LWCJM/

The actual library
https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes/tree/master/src

In this script it shows a share button with a pop up div, that shows the total shares for each of the social networks.

By default I have the button showing the caption "Shares", but when it has 0 shares, it simply displays the caption "Shares"

What ive been trying to do is work out how to display 0 next to the word shares on the button.

but no matter what I do I cant get a simple 0 to appear on the button next to the word shares.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

```
var counter_string = 0 ;

! function (a) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], a) : a(jQuery)
}(function (a) {
    "use strict";
    function b(a, b) {
        this.container = a, this.options = b, this.init()
    }
    function c(b, c) {
        this.widget = b, this.options = a.extend({}, c), this.detectService(), this.service && this.init()
    }
    function d(a) {
        function b(a, b) {
            return b.toUpper()
        }
        var c = {}, d = a.data();
        for (var e in d) {
            var f = d[e];
            "yes" === f ? f = !0 : "no" === f && (f = !1), c[e.replace(/-(\w)/g, b)] = f
        }
        return c
    }
    function e(a, b) {
        return f(a, b, encodeURIComponent)
    }
    function f(a, b, c) {
        return a.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g, function (a, d) {
            return d in b ? c ? c(b[d]) : b[d] : a
        })
    }
    function g(a, b) {
        var c = k + a;
        return c + " " + c + "_" + b
    }
    function h(b) {
        function c(f) {
            "keydown" === f.type && 27 !== f.which || a(f.target).closest(b).length || (b.removeClass(l), d.off(e, c))
        }
        var d = a(document),
            e = "click touchstart keydown";
        d.on(e, c)
    }
    function i(a, b) {
        if (document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect) {
            var c = parseInt(a.css("left"), 10),
                d = parseInt(a.css("top"), 10),
                e = a[0].getBoundingClientRect();

            e.left < b ? a.css("left", b - e.left + c) : e.right > window.innerWidth - b && a.css("left", window.innerWidth - e.right - b + c), e.top < b ? a.css("top", b - e.top + d) : e.bottom > window.innerHeight - b && a.css("top", window.innerHeight - e.bottom - b + d)
        }
        a.addClass(l)
    }
    var j = "social-likes",
        k = j + "__",
        l = j + "_opened",
        m = {
            facebook: {
                counterUrl: "http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+total_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22{url}%22&callback=?",
                convertNumber: function (a) {
                    return a.data[0].total_count
                },
                popupUrl: "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url}",
                popupWidth: 600,
                popupHeight: 500
            },
            twitter: {
                counterUrl: "http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url={url}&callback=?",
                convertNumber: function (a) {
                    return a.count
                },
                popupUrl: "http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={url}&text={title}",
                popupWidth: 600,
                popupHeight: 450,
                click: function () {
                    return /[\.:\-–—]\s*$/.test(this.options.title) || (this.options.title += ":"), !0
                }
            },
            mailru: {
                counterUrl: "http://connect.mail.ru/share_count?url_list={url}&callback=1&func=?",
                convertNumber: function (a) {
                    for (var b in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(b)) return a[b].shares
                },
                popupUrl: "http://connect.mail.ru/share?share_url={url}&title={title}",
                popupWidth: 550,
                popupHeight: 360
            },
            vkontakte: {
                counterUrl: "http://vk.com/share.php?act=count&url={url}&index={index}",
                counter: function (b, c) {
                    var d = m.vkontakte;
                    d._ || (d._ = [], window.VK || (window.VK = {}), window.VK.Share = {
                        count: function (a, b) {
                            d._[a].resolve(b)
                        }
                    });
                    var f = d._.length;
                    d._.push(c), a.getScript(e(b, {
                        index: f
                    })).fail(c.reject)
                },
                popupUrl: "http://vk.com/share.php?url={url}&title={title}",
                popupWidth: 550,
                popupHeight: 330
            },
            odnoklassniki: {
                counterUrl: "http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?st.cmd=shareData&ref={url}&cb=?",
                convertNumber: function (a) {
                    return a.count
                },
                popupUrl: "http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?st.cmd=addShare&st._surl={url}",
                popupWidth: 550,
                popupHeight: 360
            },
            plusone: {
                counterUrl: "http://share.yandex.ru/gpp.xml?url={url}",
                counter: function (b, c) {
                    var d = m.plusone;
                    return d._ ? (c.reject(), void 0) : (window.services || (window.services = {}), window.services.gplus = {
                        cb: function (a) {
                            d._.resolve(a)
                        }
                    }, d._ = c, a.getScript(e(b)).fail(c.reject), void 0)
                },
                popupUrl: "https://plus.google.com/share?url={url}",
                popupWidth: 700,
                popupHeight: 500
            },
            pinterest: {
                counterUrl: "http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url={url}&callback=?",
                convertNumber: function (a) {
                    return a.count
                },
                popupUrl: "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={url}&description={title}",
                popupWidth: 630,
                popupHeight: 270
            }
        }, n = {
            promises: {},
            fetch: function (b, c, d) {

                n.promises[b] || (n.promises[b] = {});
                var f = n.promises[b];
                if (f[c]) return f[c];
                var g = a.extend({}, m[b], d),
                    h = a.Deferred(),
                    i = g.counterUrl && e(g.counterUrl, {
                        url: c
                    });
                return a.isFunction(g.counter) ? g.counter(i, h) : g.counterUrl ? a.getJSON(i).done(function (b) {
                    try {
                        var c = b;
                        a.isFunction(g.convertNumber) && (c = g.convertNumber(b)), h.resolve(c)
                    } catch (d) {
                        h.reject()
                    }
                }).fail(h.reject) : h.reject(), f[c] = h.promise(), f[c]
            }
        };
    a.fn.socialLikes = function (c) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var e = a(this);
            new b(e, a.extend({}, a.fn.socialLikes.defaults, c, d(e)))
        })
    }, 
    a.fn.socialLikes.defaults = {
        url: window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, ""),
        title: document.title,
        counters: true,
        zeroes: true,
        wait: 500,
        singleTitle: "Share"
    }, b.prototype = {
        init: function () {
//console.log('running');

            this.container.addClass(j), this.single = this.container.hasClass(j + "_single"), this.initUserButtons(), this.number = 0, this.container.on("counter." + j, a.proxy(this.updateCounter, this)  );

            var b = this.container.children();
            this.countersLeft = b.length, this.makeSingleButton(), b.each(a.proxy(function (b, d) {
                new c(a(d), this.options)
            }, this)), this.options.counters ? this.timer = setTimeout(a.proxy(this.appear, this), this.options.wait) : this.appear()
        },
        initUserButtons: function () {
            !this.userButtonInited && window.socialLikesButtons && a.extend(!0, m, socialLikesButtons), this.userButtonInited = !0
        },



        makeSingleButton: function () {
            if (this.single) {
                var b = this.container;
                b.addClass(j + "_vertical"), b.wrap(a("<div>", {
                    "class": j + "_single-w"
                }));

                var c = b.parent(),
                    d = parseInt(b.css("left"), 10),
                    e = parseInt(b.css("top"), 10),
                    m = a("<div>", {
                        "class": g("widget", "single")
                    }),
                    n = a(f('<div class="{buttonCls}" id="counter-wrapper"><span class="{iconCls}"></span>{title}</div>', 
                    {
                        buttonCls: g("button", "single"),
                        iconCls: g("icon", "single"),
                        title: this.options.singleTitle
                    }));

//    buttonCounter(this.options.singleTitle) 
//buttonCounter(this.options.singleTitle)

                m.append(n), c.append(m), m.click(function () {
                    return b.css({
                        left: d,
                        top: e
                    }), i(b, 20), h(b), !1
                });
                var o = a("<div>", {
                    "class": k + "close",
                    html: "&times;"
                });
                b.append(o), o.click(function () {
                    b.removeClass(l)
                }), this.widget = m
            }
        },





        updateCounter: function (a, b, c) 
        {
            c && (
                   this.number += c, this.single && this.getCounterElem().text(this.number)
                 ), 
            this.countersLeft--, 0 === this.countersLeft && (this.appear(), this.container.addClass(j + "_ready"), this.container.trigger("ready." + j, this.number))            
        },
        appear: function () {
             this.container.addClass(j + "_visible")

        },
        getCounterElem: function () {
            var b = this.widget.find("." + k + "counter_single");

            return b.length || (b = a("<span>", {
                "class": g("counter", "single")
            }), this.widget.append(b)      ), b
        }
    }, c.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            if (this.detectParams(), this.initHtml(), this.options.counters) if (this.options.counterNumber) this.updateCounter(this.options.counterNumber);
            else {
                var b = this.options.counterUrl ? {
                    counterUrl: this.options.counterUrl
                } : {};
                n.fetch(this.service, this.options.url, b).always(a.proxy(this.updateCounter, this))

            }
        },
        detectService: function () {
            for (var b = this.widget[0].classList || this.widget[0].className.split(" "), c = 0; c < b.length; c++) {
                var d = b[c];
                if (m[d]) return this.service = d, a.extend(this.options, m[d]), void 0
            }
        },
        detectParams: function () {
            var a = this.widget.data();
            if (a.counter) {
                var b = parseInt(a.counter, 10);
                isNaN(b) ? this.options.counterUrl = a.counter : this.options.counterNumber = b
            }
            a.title && (this.options.title = a.title), a.url && (this.options.url = a.url)
        },
        initHtml: function () {
            var b = this.options,
                c = this.widget,
                d = c.find("a");
            d.length && this.cloneDataAttrs(d, c);
            var f = a("<span>", {
                "class": this.getElementClassNames("button"),
                text: c.text()
            });
            if (b.clickUrl) {
                var g = e(b.clickUrl, {
                    url: b.url,
                    title: b.title
                }),
                    h = a("<a>", {
                        href: g
                    });
                this.cloneDataAttrs(c, h), c.replaceWith(h), this.widget = c = h
            } else c.click(a.proxy(this.click, this));
            c.removeClass(this.service), c.addClass(this.getElementClassNames("widget")), f.prepend(a("<span>", {
                "class": this.getElementClassNames("icon")
            })), c.empty().append(f), this.button = f
        },
        cloneDataAttrs: function (a, b) {
            var c = a.data();
            for (var d in c) c.hasOwnProperty(d) && b.data(d, c[d])
        },
        getElementClassNames: function (a) {
            return g(a, this.service)
        },
        updateCounter: function (b) {
            if (b = parseInt(b, 10) || 0, b || this.options.zeroes) {
                var c = a("<span>", 
                {
                    "class": this.getElementClassNames("counter"),
                    text: b
                }

                );
                console.log(c);
                this.widget.append(c)

            }
            this.widget.trigger("counter." + j, [this.service, b])
            //console.log(b);
        },
        click: function (b) {

            var c = this.options,
                d = !0;
            if (a.isFunction(c.click) && (d = c.click.call(this, b)), d) {

                var f = e(c.popupUrl, {
                    url: c.url,
                    title: c.title
                });
                f = this.addAdditionalParamsToUrl(f), this.openPopup(f, {
                    width: c.popupWidth,
                    height: c.popupHeight
                })
            }
            return !1
        },
        addAdditionalParamsToUrl: function (b) {
            var c = a.param(this.widget.data());
            if (!c) return b;
            var d = -1 === b.indexOf("?") ? "?" : "&";
            return b + d + c
        },
        openPopup: function (a, b) {
            var c = Math.round(screen.width / 2 - b.width / 2),
                d = 0;
            screen.height > b.height && (d = Math.round(screen.height / 3 - b.height / 2));
            var e = window.open(a, "sl_" + this.service, "left=" + c + ",top=" + d + ",width=" + b.width + ",height=" + b.height + ",personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
            e ? e.focus() : location.href = a

        }
    }, a(function () {
        a("." + j).socialLikes()
    })
//console.log(counter_string);
});

function buttonCounter(defaultString)
{
return defaultString;

}
```

Comment: Add a zero in the html manually? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: i need to add it in dynamically, so if the total share count is 0, it only cr=urrently displays "Shares" I need it to display "0 Shares"

Comment: Where in this code do you count the shares together?

Comment: thats what I have been hunting for. I cant seem to track it down anywhere.

Here is a link to the actual source on the git hub project - https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes/blob/master/src/social-likes.js but even on here i cant seem to track it down

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need to use [zeroes option](https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes#options):

```
<ul class="social-likes" data-zeroes="yes">
    …
</ul>
```